# How to read from a JSON file with unescaped backslashes?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, escaping

I have a JSON file that contains a connection string:

**abc.json**

```
{
  "host":"1.2.3.4",
  "user":"abc",
  "passwd":"s&]\yz$&u42/",
  "dbname":"sample",
  "port":2341
}
```

Here's my Python script which tries to read the data:

```
 import psycopg2 as pg
 dbconn = "C:\abc.json"
 with open(dbconn) as conn_file:
     conn = json.load(conn_file)
```

It gives me this error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 4 column 16 (char 53)
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: By the way ... if that's a real password, you'll want to change it right away.

Comment: That's a wrong password so it's fine!

Answer (score 9):

Your file is not valid: there's no such escape sequence as `\y` in JSON, and bare backslashes must themselves be escaped thus: `\\`.

The simplest solution, if you can, is to fix your file so that it is valid JSON, by escaping that backslash.

If for some reason you can't, it's possible to write a wrapper for `json.loads()` that catches this specific error and patches up the source text:

```
import json
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError

def permissive_json_loads(text):
    while True:
        try:
            data = json.loads(text)
        except JSONDecodeError as exc:
            if exc.msg == 'Invalid \\escape':
                text = text[:exc.pos] + '\\' + text[exc.pos:]
            else:
                raise
        else:
            return data
```

For the sake of simplicity, the function above takes a string rather than a file.

It's also something of a "sledgehammer to crack a nut" approach, repeatedly trying to load the whole JSON document and fixing any unescaped backslashes as it finds them – which is reasonable for small JSON documents that rarely have the problem, but less appropriate if you're handling large JSON documents with lots of these unescaped backslash errors.

Here it is in action:

```
>>> print(text)
{
  "host":"1.2.3.4",
  "user":"abc",
  "passwd":"s&]\yz$&u42/",
  "dbname":"sample",
  "port":2341
}

>>> config = permissive_json_loads(text)
>>> print(config['passwd'])
s&]\yz$&u42/
```

In your case, you'd read from your file into a string, and call the function on that:

```
 dbconn = "C:\abc.json"
 with open(dbconn) as conn_file:
     conn_doc = conn_file.read()
 conn = permissive_json_loads(conn_doc)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I have tried storing the contents in a text file and running through this caused an error : son.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0), please could you suggest if I read it from a file will that be an issue?

Comment: Did you pass the filename to the function, by any chance? The function above takes a string containing the JSON as an argument, not a filename. You'll need to open and read the file into a string first.

Comment: It would be possible to rewrite the function so that it took a file or filename, but in cases like this where you're trying to patch up malformed data, it's a good idea to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: yes, I have mentioned a filename. The idea is to keep this configuration file in a separate place so need a file to be read from. Please could you help in achieving that?

Comment: How to read a file into a string is a separate (and very basic, to be honest) question, but I've edited the answer to show how.

Comment: Thank you Zero, It's working with python 3.6 but not 2.7. I will try to solve it..Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Please could you help me in getting it done using python 2.7?

Comment: It turns out that the `json` module in Python 2.7 raises a `ValueError` with no special attributes like `pos`, so a handler would be more fragile ... and `permissive_json_loads()` is already at the outer edge of what I'd consider an acceptable risk in terms of trying to fix broken data. Unless there's absolutely no way you can, I would **strongly** recommend just fixing your invalid JSON instead.

Comment: (I'm bailing at this point, by the way. Especially when you're handling stuff like passwords, it's dangerous to just throw code you don't understand at a problem rather than dealing with it properly, and I feel it would be irresponsible of me to go any further).

Answer (score 1):

Python >= 2.7.15 seems to produce the same error message as Python3:

```
test = """
{
  "host":"1.2.3.4",
  "user":"abc",
  "passwd":"s&]\yz$&u42/",
  "dbname":"sample",
  "port":2341
}
"""

print json.loads(test)
```

Error:

> ValueError: Invalid \escape: line 5 column 16 (char 54)

Modifying [@Zero Piraeus's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1014938/zero-piraeus) code slightly makes it work under Python2.7:

```
import json
import re

def permissive_json_loads(text):
    _rePattern = re.compile(r'''(\d+)\)$''', re.MULTILINE)

    i = 0
    #  Make sure the loop is going to terminate.
    #  There wont be more iterations than the double amout of characters
    while True:
        i += 1
        if i > len(text) * 2:
            return
        try:
            data = json.loads(text)
        except ValueError, exc:
            exMsg = str(exc)
            if exMsg.startswith('Invalid \\escape'):
                m = re.search(_rePattern, exMsg)
                if not m:
                    return

                pos = int(m.groups()[0])
                print "Replacing at: %d" % pos
                text = text[:pos] + '\\' + text[pos:]
            else:
                raise
        else:
            return data

text = """
{
  "host":"1.2.3.4",
  "user":"abc",
  "passwd":"s&]\yz$&u42/",
  "dbname":"sample",
  "port":2341
}
"""

i = permissive_json_loads(text)
print i
```

Prints:

```
Replacing at position: 54
{u'passwd': u's&]\\yz$&u42/', u'host': u'1.2.3.4', u'port': 2341, u'user': u'abc', u'dbname': u'sample'}
```