# How to send data without processing escape sequences to neo4j?

Tags: python, json, neo4j

I have a file containing JSON data. It contains values like `"st": "\\F\\"` 
But when I try to upload the data I am getting the following error- 
`neobolt.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: Invalid input 'F': expected '\', ''', '"', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't', UTF16 or UTF32`

The error occurred during the creation of following node - 
`MERGE (a:st {Name: '\F\'})`.

I want the information to go like - 
`MERGE (a:st {Name: '\\F\\'})`
Is there a way to allow python to send data without processing the escape sequences.

Comment: How does your code "send data"?

Comment: ```with open ("hl7.json", "r") as r:
    data = r.read()
    data = json.loads(data, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
createMasterGraph( data )```

Comment: I think the problem may be the _trailing_ `"\"` character in the value. See if you can verify that (sorry, I don't have `neo4j` installed). If that's the case, you should be able to process the data after the `json.loads()` call and remove them from all affected values in the file.

Comment: This question has an answer that *might* be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207105/how-to-read-from-a-json-file-with-unescaped-backslashes