# Parsing invalid JSON with Python - invalid escapes causing errors

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, escaping

I'm parsing 'JSON' which is normally correct, but certain entries contain regex patterns which throw errors during `json.load`

E.g

```
 "pattern" : [
                        {
                            "data" : ".*\x 39 44 2D 52 51 4D 54 2D 48 46 2D 41 52 4D 30 31 2E 70 64 66 78 \x.*"
                        }
                        ],
```

Throws an error:

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
351         """
352         try:
--> 353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
354         except StopIteration as err:
355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 18419 column 45 (char 595400)
```

What is the correct way to handle this?

Currently I'm just trying (although having tried other variations of 'unicode-escape'):

```
with open("json-file.json", "r") as original_file:
    file = json.load(original_file)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read from a JSON file with unescaped backslashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207105/how-to-read-from-a-json-file-with-unescaped-backslashes)

Comment: You pasted that after I answered below... :|